# Laravel file not saved but recorded in database

Tags: php, laravel, lamp

I am accepting a file and some other parameters with it. I validate the file and the parameters and then I store the file while making a record in the database. Pretty standard stuff. The issue I have is that a majority of my files and records get saved but sometimes there exists a record in the database but there is no file associated with it saved. I have tried reproducing it but I haven't been able to. I don't know if the error is my code, or my server or if the user prematurely loses connection or some other issue of that nature.

I am running Laravel 7 on AWS Lightsail instance with Bitnami LAMP stack.

#### Store Method in  Controller

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $filePath = $request
        ->file('file')
        ->storeAs(
            'path',
            Str::upper($request->input('param1')) .
                "_{$request->input('param2')}_{$request->input(
                    'param3'
                )}_{$request->input('param4')}_{$request->input(
                    'param5'
                )}_" .
                now()->format('Ymd_Hi') .
                ".{$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension()}",
            'public'
        );

    Storage::setVisibility('public/' . $filePath, 'private');

    $record = Model::create(
        array_merge($request->all(), ['file' => $filePath])
    );

    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('message', 'File submitted successfully');
}
```

#### Rules in StoreRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        //rules for other parameters
        'filetype' => ['required', 'string'],
    ];

    if (request('filetype') === 'video') {
        $rules['file'] = [
            'required',
            'file',
            'mimetypes:video/*',
            'max:200000',
        ];
    } elseif (request('filetype') === 'image') {
        $rules['file'] = ['required', 'file', 'image', 'max:20000'];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

I have 259 records on the database but I have only received 247 files. Where could the error lie? I have tried on my development environment but I haven't been able to reproduce an error like this. Is it something to do with my php.ini settings? Is it something that the user is causing? How can the file not be saved when I am saving it before the record gets stored in the database?

Comment: Straight off the bat, I'd suggest that it's an issue with your path names. These can be the same if you submit the file in the same minute? if I'm reading your path correctly.

Comment: find a record in the database which is missing, then check all the rows which are 'after' it, to see when the file does exist

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_storeAs will return a bool (false) if it doesn't work, so just don't save the record and ask user to try again

Comment: Yes. That is true. I have not accounted for files which could be saved in the same minute with the same parameters. I do receive entries like that which are spaced closely together. I'll add seconds too and a UUID

Comment: @FelippeDuarte wouldn't the record show that? The $filePath variable would be false if it didn't get saved wouldn't it?

Comment: @Ballard You are right. I just dumped the rows and checked for duplicate values and son of gun, there are exactly 12 duplicate values (259-247) - same parameters submitted within the same minute. Man I would have never expected that. The user literally has to fill out 5 parameters and they managed to do that AND upload a file in the same minute. Thank you so much. I'll be more than happy to accept that as the right answer if you were to post it. This was my first VPS server, so I was plucking hairs thinking it was something in the server or some other race condition.

Comment: @Arjun I've had the battlescars from this... use timestring :) - added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ymd_Hi which would not allow for any records saved in the same minute, perhaps use a timestring or include seconds too, but be warned, if you use seconds you may face the same issue!

Comment: I want the file name to be readable too as the files are going to be classified later on with their name. I have added seconds. I'll add a check to see if the file exists and if it does just increment the second by one. Would that cause any problems down the road?

Comment: if you've got the file names in the database, does it really matter if they're readable? you can add a column to the table called 'friendly_name' if you want to

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in pho.ini file. One is upload_max_filesize and another one post_max_size. While uploading the file I think it crosses the size that defined in ini file.
If your video size 200 MB then upload_max_size should be more than or equal 200 MB.  post_max_size is total size of form that going to be submitted.  It is safer to set size more than upload_max_size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and interest in the question. That wasn't the issue here. I had increased both of them. As @Ballard had pointed out the issue was that users submitted two files with the same parameters in the same minute.